# Simultaneous overset and superscript

Tags: superscripts

When I type `$\overset{\circ}{Z}^\lambda$` the lambda is placed slightly above and to the right of the circle. Is there a way to make it appear as a superscript on the Z? I tried `$\overset{\circ}{Z^\lambda}$`, but then the circle is too high and to the right.

As a bizarre aside: a friend uses the exact same code with no problem. However, when I type it into MathOverflow it looks the same as in my compiler (i.e. bad).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `accents` package lets you define `circ` as a math accent. The result is slightly larger than `\mathring`. Note in the `\overset` solution, `\circ` is not well placed (horizontally speaking):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \verb+\overset+ & \verb+\mathring+ & \verb+\accentset+ \\[2ex]
  $ \smash[t]{\overset{\circ}{Z}}^\lambda $ & $ \mathring{Z}^\lambda $ & $ \accentset{\circ}{Z}^\lambda $
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

My impression is that you're using the wrong tool:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\mathring{Z}^\lambda$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want a bigger circle, then something like

```
\newcommand{\rZ}{%
  \vphantom{\rrZ}% get the height right
  \smash{\rrZ}% print the item without height
  {\vphantom{Z}}% provide a atom the superscript is attached to
}
\newcommand{\rrZ}{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\,\circ}{Z}}
```

can do.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Slight variation that saves typing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\cZ{\overset{\circ}{Z}\vphantom{Z}}
\begin{document}
$\cZ^\lambda$
\end{document}
```

[image]