# How can I put a symbol or text over another text as shown in the formula in latex by overleaf

Tags: math-mode, equations

[image][image: Formula LVQ]

I have been trying to look for a solution to this
How can I put a symbol or text over another text as shown in the formula in latex by overleaf? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For stacking symbols there is the `\overset` macro from the `amsmath` package. Combining that with superscripts is however not trivial; have a look at [Simultaneous overset and superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256347/82917).

Comment: @campa it works! thank you so much